VS webview2 Add Browser Extension
I am Developing a Custom Browser For  Using VS 2022 WinForm With WebView2
I need To Add Unpacked Browser Extension.
Coded
Error I am Getting
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  HResult=0x80070032
  Message=The request is not supported. (0x80070032)
  Source=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Profile.<AddBrowserExtensionAsync>d__63.MoveNext()

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Profile.AddBrowserExtensionAsync(string)

Any Solution Will Be Thanked.

After some tests, I also got the same error as yours. According to this official document, AreBrowserExtensionsEnabled defaults to false. If it is not set to true, installed extensions will not be available in the user profile:

When AreBrowserExtensionsEnabled is set to true, new extensions can be
added to user profile and used. AreBrowserExtensionsEnabled is default
to be false, in this case, new extensions can't be installed, and
already installed extension won't be available to use in user profile.

Even if I set AreBrowserExtensionsEnabled to true, this error still occurs. I suggest you submit this issue to Github for further help.
